# Typescript library Plugin problem with compiled code for es5 project

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

Trying to create my first Typescript application which can be compiled to ES5 but running into issues where `Create` is not being found.

I'm aiming to get the user to type `create.name.firstName(1)` and it will return the gender initially as a first step but really struggling here.

Would love some help getting this set up so it will work as expected.

`index.ts`

```
import { Name } from './name';

interface CreateTypes {
  locale?: any;
  locales?: any;
  localeFallback?: any;
  name?: any;
}

export class Create {
  public self: CreateTypes = {};
  public locales: any;
  public locale: any;
  public localeFallback: any;

  constructor(options: any) {
    this.self = {
      locale: options.locale || {},
      locales: options.locales || 'en',
      localeFallback: options.localeFallback || 'en',
    };

    this.locales = this.self.locales;
    this.locale = this.self.locale;
    this.localeFallback = this.self.localeFallback;
    this.self.name = new Name(self);
  }
}
```

`name.ts`

```
export class Name {
  constructor(create: any) {
    console.log('[CLASS] Name');
    console.log(create);
    console.log('[CLASS] Name');
  }

  /**
   * firstName
   *
   * @method firstName
   * @param {mixed} gender
   * @memberof create.name
   */
  firstName(gender: boolean): boolean {
    console.log(gender);
    return gender;
  }
}
```

compiled index.js

```
/*!
 * createusers v0.0.0
 * (c) [authorFullName]
 * Released under the MIT License.
 */

'use strict';

Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', { value: true });

var Name = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Name(create) {
        console.log('[CLASS] Name');
        console.log(create);
        console.log('[CLASS] Name');
    }
    /**
     * firstName
     *
     * @method firstName
     * @param {mixed} gender
     * @memberof create.name
     */
    Name.prototype.firstName = function (gender) {
        console.log(gender);
        return gender;
    };
    return Name;
}());

var Create = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Create(options) {
        this.self = {};
        this.self = {
            locale: options.locale || {},
            locales: options.locales || 'en',
            localeFallback: options.localeFallback || 'en',
        };
        this.locales = this.self.locales;
        this.locale = this.self.locale;
        this.localeFallback = this.self.localeFallback;
        this.self.name = new Name(self);
    }
    return Create;
}());

exports.Create = Create;
//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map
```

`demo.html`

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script> var exports = {}; </script>
    <script src="../dist/index.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have compiled your file to be a esmodule file that exports the `Create` class. How are you importing this compiled file?

Comment: @Terry I have updated the code to show you the demo html file. I've been using console log to try use the code eg `Create.name` and so on to see what the responses are

Comment: @Terry Actually they transpiled it to a commonjs module. Which won't work in the browser.

Comment: @Bergi not sure the best way to transpile them for browser. I used this boilerplate https://github.com/VitorLuizC/typescript-library-boilerplate